# How to skip a record in COBOL with an if statement

Tags: cobol

```
              FD  STUDENTS-FILE-IN.
   01  STUDENTS-RECORD-IN.
       05  SSN-IN                  PIC X(9).
       05  STUDENT-NAME-IN         PIC X(11).
       05                          PIC X(5).
       05  GRAD-STATUS-IN          PIC X.
       05  CLASS-STANDING-IN       PIC X.
       05  MAJOR-IN                PIC X(3).
       05  CREDIT-HOURS-IN         PIC 9(3).
       05  CREDIT-POINTS-IN        PIC 9(3).

   FD  STUDENTS-FILE-OUT.
   01  STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT         PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS      PIC X(3)  VALUE 'YES'.
   01  PAGE-NUMBER                 PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.
   01  LINE-COUNT                  PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.
   01  SSID-BREAK.
       03 FIRST-PART               PIC X(3).
       03 SECOND-PART              PIC X(2).
       03 THIRD-PART               PIC X(4).
   01  NAME-BREAK.
       03 FIRST-LETTER             PIC X(1).
       03 MIDDLE-LETTER            PIC X(1).
       03 LAST-LETTER              PIC X(10).
   01  GRAD-CHECK                  PIC X.
   01  WS-DATE.
       05 RUN-YEAR                 PIC XX.
       05 RUN-MONTH                PIC XX.
       05 RUN-DAY                  PIC XX.

   01  HEADING-LINE-ONE.
       05                          PIC X(21) VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(33)
               VALUE 'RHODES STATE COLLEGE GRADE REPORT'.
       05                          PIC X(6) VALUE SPACES.
       05      HEADING-LINE-DATE.
               10  MONTH-NOW       PIC XX.
               10                  PIC X     VALUE '/'.
               10  DAY-NOW         PIC XX.
               10                  PIC X     VALUE '/'.
               10  YEAR-NOW        PIC XX.

       05                          PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(4)  VALUE 'PAGE'.
       05  HL-1-PAGE-NUMBER        PIC Z9    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  HEADING-LINE-TWO.
       05                          PIC X(10) VALUE 'SOC SEC NO'.
       05                          PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(12) VALUE 'STUDENT NAME'.
       05                          PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(8)  VALUE 'STANDING'.
       05                          PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(5)  VALUE 'MAJOR'.
       05                          PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(5)  VALUE 'HOURS'.
       05                          PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(6)  VALUE 'POINTS'.
       05                          PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(3)  VALUE 'GPA'.

   01  DETAIL-LINE.

       05  DL-SSID.
           10 SSID-1               PIC X(3).
           10                      PIC X     VALUE "-".
           10 SSID-2               PIC X(2).
           10                      PIC X     VALUE "-".
           10 SSID-3               PIC X(4).
       05  BLANK-B                 PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  DL-NAME .
           10 FIRST-INI            PIC X.
           10                      PIC X     VALUE SPACES.
           10 MID-INI              PIC X.
           10                      PIC X     VALUE SPACES.
           10 LAST-NAME            PIC X(10).

       05  BLANK-C                 PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  YEAR-STATUS             PIC X(9).
       05  BLANK-D                 PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  STUDENT-MAJOR           PIC X(13).
       05  BLANK-E                 PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  STUDNET-HOURS           PIC ZZ9.
       05  BLANK-F                 PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  STUDENT-POINTS          PIC ZZ9.
       05  BLANK-G                 PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.
       05  STUDENT-GPA             PIC 9V99.

   01  TOTALS-LINE.

       05 TOTALS                   PIC X(6)  VALUE 'TOTALS'.
       05                          PIC X(34) VALUE  SPACES.
       05 HITS-TOTAL               PIC ZZZ,ZZZ.
       05                          PIC X(9) VALUE SPACES.
       05 BATS-TOTAL               PIC ZZZ,ZZZ.
       05                          PIC X(10) VALUE  SPACES.
       05 AVG-TOTAL                PIC .999.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.
       OPEN INPUT STUDENTS-FILE-IN
       OPEN OUTPUT STUDENTS-FILE-OUT

       ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE
       MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-NOW
       MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-NOW
       MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-NOW

       PERFORM 300-WRITE-HEADINGS

       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
           READ STUDENTS-FILE-IN
               AT END
                    MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
                NOT AT END
                    PERFORM 200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD
            END-READ
        END-PERFORM

       CLOSE STUDENTS-FILE-IN
       CLOSE STUDENTS-FILE-OUT
       STOP RUN.

   200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.

       IF  LINE-COUNT >= 53
          PERFORM 300-WRITE-HEADINGS
       END-IF


  *    IF  GRAD-STATUS-IN NOT = '1' AND NOT = '2'
  *        PERFORM 400-WRITE-TOTALS.
  *    END-IF

       MOVE SSN-IN TO SSID-BREAK
       MOVE FIRST-PART TO SSID-1
       MOVE SECOND-PART TO SSID-2
       MOVE THIRD-PART TO SSID-3
       MOVE STUDENT-NAME-IN TO NAME-BREAK
       MOVE FIRST-LETTER TO FIRST-INI
       MOVE MIDDLE-LETTER TO MID-INI
       MOVE LAST-LETTER TO LAST-NAME
       MOVE GRAD-STATUS-IN TO GRAD-CHECK
       IF  GRAD-CHECK = 'Y'

       END-IF



       MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT

       WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES
       ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT.
```

The input file looks like this

```
307662099KRAlexander     Y2NES005017
```

Basically certain files won't meet the requirements and we are just suppose to just skip over them. This is an example of the file that we don't want to write to the output file and skip over. I apologize if I explained this poorly but I am really struggling with COBOL.

Answer (score 1):

Your 200- paragraph needs to do something like this:

```
IF NOT ( <condition-for-skipping )
    PERFORM PROCESS-THIS-RECORD
ELSE 
    PERFORM IGNORE-THIS-RECORD
END-IF
```

You can swap the conditions easily

```
IF ( <condition-for-skipping )
    PERFORM IGNORE-THIS-RECORD
ELSE 
    PERFORM PROCESS-THIS-RECORD
END-IF
```

All the stuff you have in the 200- paragraph currently, you put in to a new paragrpah PROCESS-THIS-RECORD. You should have a new paragraph IGNORE-THIS-RECORD. If nothing else, it can count the records which are ignored. Then if you count the records which are processed, and count the input records, at the end you can check that everything is either processed or ignored.

You should check file-statuses. It is good to use scope-delimiters (like the END-IF) and keep full-stops/periods to a minimum.

88s are good to use for conditions. Saves lots of literals hanging about to make maintenance more complex.